# Whats the best way to created a filtered tableview from a Firebase Database using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase-realtime-database

I have a tableview that displays the titles of songs that pulls from a Firebase Database that contains the following structure:

```
{
  "songs" : {
    "key1" : {
      "lyrics" : "...",
      "title" : "...",
      "video" : "..."
    }
  }
}
```

If I add the firebase data to a class called Song then I think I can do this:

```
var songs = [Song]()
var filteredSongs = [Song]()

let lower = searchBar.text!.lowercaseString
filteredSongs = songs.filter({$0.title.rangeOfString(lower) != nil})
```

However, I'm not succeeding in doing that after following the example of this solution to this question: [convert FIRDataSnapshot to custom type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38360006/6291832)

```
class Song: NSObject {
 var title: String
 var lyrics: String
 var videoUrl: String
let ref: FIRDatabaseReference?

init(title: String, lyrics: String, videoUrl: String) {
    self.title = title
    self.lyrics = lyrics
    self.videoUrl = videoUrl
    self.ref = nil
}

init(snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) {
    title = snapshot.value!["title"] as! String
    lyrics = snapshot.value!["lyrics"] as! String
    videoUrl = snapshot.value!["video"] as! String
    ref = snapshot.ref
}

convenience override init() {
    self.init(title: "", lyrics: "", videoUrl: "")
}   
}
```

Is there a way to add a filter without creating a class?

Comment: Is there any error you are getting after applying `filter` to `songs` array ?

Comment: where and how do you declare `lower` var? And share you `Song` class.

Comment: @Igor I just updated the question to add `lower`

Comment: @triple.s I'm getting an `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` after trying to implement the class `Song` and using that to generate the tableview. I didn't even try to apply a filter yet because that's breaking.

Comment: try `print(filteredSongs)`. What in log you get?

Comment: how do you fetch the data to songs and where reload table?

Comment: The attribute values of your snapshot children contain `nil` values. The best way to handle `nil` is to declare your model attributes as `Optional`. Try making all attributes as Optional as `var title: String?,  var lyrics: String?, var videoUrl: String? `

Comment: @ChaseMcElroy If you feel your question has been satisfied, please vote on an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's preferable to convert your JSON to structs/classes in your Model layer, so that's easier to work with in the Controller layer.

Barring that, you can do something like:

```
json.value!["songs"].filter{ ($0.value!["title"] as! String).rangeOfString(lower) != nil}
```

As you can see, it's ugly. Don't do this.

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem in another part of code, than you share.

Put a breakpoint and execute code line by line. You find a line, which throw exception. If will have a question, ask with share this line of code.