# How to associate to different data objects in Firebase 3 with each other using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-realtime-database, data-objects

I know in SQL to associate 2 different objects with each other one would use a primary key in 1 table and a foreign key in another table. Since FirebaseDatabase uses JSON/NoSQL that's not possible. If I had 2 objects being UserPostEntity and PostEntity, once a user made a post/comment how would I associate a UserPostEntity with a PostEntity and how would the PostEntity be automatically updated with that post/comment the user made?

UserEntity Object:

```
import Foundation

    class UserEntity{

        var userID: String
        var postedComment: String
        var postDate: String
        var postID: PostEntity

        init(userID: String, postedComment: String, postDate: String, postID: PostEntity){
            self.userID = userID
            self.postedComment = postedComment
            self.postDate = postDate
            self.postID = postID
        }
    }
```

PostEntity Object:

```
import Foundation

class PostEntity{

    var userID: String
    var postID: String
    var postedComment: String
    var postDate: String

    init(userID: String, postID: String, postedComment: String, postDate: String){
        self.userID = userID
        self.postID = postID
        self.postedComment = postedComment
        self.postDate = postDate
    }
}
```

Comment: What's difference between your `UserEntity` and `PostEntity` ? They have the same attributes !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be better if you could structure your data in Firebase. Here is the links that provide nice intuition about structuring data in Firebase:

https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/04/denormalizing-your-data-is-normal.html
https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/structuring-data.html

You can define your `user` table and `posts` as follow:

```
user{
    "u1" {
    
         userName : "abc",
         posts {
              p1 : true,
              p2 : true
          }
        },
        
        "u2" {
    
         userName : "def",
         posts {
              p3 : true,
              p4 : true
          }
        }
        
  }
  
  post{
        "p1"{
            userId : "u1",
            postComment : "hello ios",
            postDate : "1467570919"
            },
        "p2"{
            userId : "u1",
            postComment : "ios",
            postDate : "1467570920"
            },
        "p3"{
            userId : "u2",
            postComment : "hello ios",
            postDate : "1467570921"
            },
        "p4"{
            userId : "u2",
            postComment : "hello ios",
            postDate : "1467570922"
            }
    }
```

Also you can creates your entities as follow:

```
class UserEntity{

        var userID: String
        var userName : String
        var posts: Dictionary<String, Bool>?
        var ref : FIRDatabaseReference?

        init(userID: String, userName: String, posts: Dictionary<String, Bool>?){
            self.userID = userID
            self.userName = userName
            self.posts = posts
            self.ref = nil
        }
    }
    
    
    class PostEntity{

    var pId: String
    var uId: String
    var postedComment: String
    var postDate: NSTimeInterval
    var ref : FIRDatabaseReference?

    init(pId: String, uId: String, postedComment: String, postDate: NSTimeInterval){
        self.pId= pId
        self.uId = uId
        self.postedComment = postedComment
        self.postDate = postDate
        self.ref = nil
    }
}
```

Also you would want to structure your `UserEntity` and `PostEntity` entity as answered in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38359410/convert-firdatasnapshot-to-custom-type/38360006#38360006).

You have to update the `posts` attribute of `user` table as `p5 :true`, when a new post `p5` is added by user `u1`.

Comment: HI, thanks for the help. Quick question, what's the purpose of the ref: FIRDatabaseReference? They are both set to nil so what's the purpose?

Comment: `ref` is to keep track of the reference to the path in database where you data is present. For e.g. incase of `UserEntity` is is path to `user` table and incase of `PostEntity`, it is path to the `post` table.

Comment: `ref` will help when you retrieve data from firebase. For each entity you don't have to look up for a reference. It will present as its attribute.